# Deleted default OS (Ubuntu) from dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I deleted sda1-fat32,sda8-ext4 and sda6 Linux-swap. Error message is_E61: Media test failure, Exiting PXE ROM. When boot from hard drive
-Reboot and Select proper boot device or insert boot media. Booting from dvd/pen drive either Ubuntu or Windows 7 becomes inactive after it has loaded files. Files not a problem. Dell Inspiron N5110 lap. Please suggest me a way.

Comment: You may have deleted the boot partition (sda1?) and thus the system cannot boot from HDD. Your best bet is probably to backup your files and do a factory reset.

Comment: Sir, I tried to Windows with recovery cd.  Factory reset also failed.(error).

Comment: If you're trying to reinstall Windows, I suggest you ask in another stackexchange community, because here is dedicated to Ubuntu only.

Comment: No sir, I  had grub error first. So I wanted to delete and reinstall Ubuntu. Infact  I  depend on Ubuntu more. I don't mind  loosing Windows.

Comment: Deleting the Ubuntu partition caused the issue with grub then. Grub saves files in the Ubuntu partition. Reinstall Ubuntu from live USB, install using the something else option and recreate the Ubuntu partitions. Make sure you select `/dev/sda` for grub installation.

Comment: But sir , the live usb stops after it has loaded files.ubuntu theme is there, but no menu . Screen is inactive. Chance for hardware failure?